# Rails:How to GET mutiple params from URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, url

Now I'm using GET to request params of only one obj at a time.

For example

```
def show
   @targetrecord=TargetRecord.find(id)
   render json: @targetrecord
end
```

And the corresponding url is http://locaolhost:3000/model/show/:id

If I want to change the url to something like http://locaolhost:3000/model/show?id=123,name=ABC,number=10...

where the "numer=10" in the link means that I want to GET "10" obj named "ABC" in jason.

How can I modify my code and which part of it? Thanks!!

Comment: can you be more specific? You want to read the params from the URL in rails controller?

Comment: I want to filter what kind of obj I want to GET.
like .../show?name=ABC,number=10... means that with this GET request, I can get 10 obj named ABC and their detail with jason. So it will respond to  GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access request params using `params` in controller:

```
params[:id] # 123
params[:number] # 10
```

I suggest it better if you use the URL like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/model/1?name=ABC&number=10
```

Comment: thanks! But what if that "number" is not part of the obj params? It's just a number that tells the controller to return how many of the obj?

Comment: I made it! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I'm glad this helps!